# html Select List add values with c#

Tags: c#, selectlist

I have following manual code to open the URLs:

```
<select type="text" name="sel_veh" id="Select1" runat="server"  onchange="window.open('http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptest&report=eth_fleet_dtl&veh_num='+ sel_veh.value,'mywindow4');" language="javascript" onclick="return sel_veh_onclick()" style="font-size: 10pt">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="01-01-12">01-Jan</option>
    <option value="01-02-12">02-Jan</option>
    <option value="01-02-12">03-Jan</option>
    <option value="01-02-12">04-Jan</option>
</select>
```

I have this `select` list with hard-coded date values. The problem is that when date changes, I have to update the code with new dates. Is there any way in C# that I can add values to this `select` list by c3 code dynamically that date values should auto change with system date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. if you're looking into a more coder-friendly control, use the [DropDownList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) control

if you're using a `<select />`, you can add items by

```
Select1.Items.Add("01-01-12","01-Jan");
```

for example

if you're using a `DropDownList`, you can add items by

```
dropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("01-Jan", "01-01-12"));
```

Comment: But It Will again a fixed Value.I want to add using loop that prvious 7 dates should remain in list

Comment: You can change it as you would like - you can use the DateTime class to generate dates, get the current date, etc

Comment: How to use dateadd attriubte to select list like here in dropdownlist   DD2.Items.Add(New ListItem(Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "dd-MMM"), Format(DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, Now), "dd-MMM-yyyy")))

Answer (score 0):

First, as Shai correctly said use DropDownList control instead:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDates" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Now populate it from code behind with such code:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime past = now.AddDays(-7);
List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
for (DateTime curDate = past; curDate <= now; curDate = curDate.AddDays(1))
    dates.Add(curDate);
ddlDates.Attributes["onchange"] = "window.open('http://appsrv01.shakarganj.com.pk:7778/reports/rwservlet?reptest&report=eth_fleet_dtl&veh_num='+ this.value, 'mywindow4');";
ddlDates.Attributes["onclick"] = "return sel_veh_onclick();";
ddlDates.Items.Clear();
ddlDates.Items.Add(new ListItem("Please Select", ""));
ddlDates.Items.AddRange(dates.ConvertAll(dt => new ListItem(dt.ToString("dd-MMM"), dt.ToString("MM-dd-yy"))).ToArray());
```

Comment: Shadow Wizard Can I sort Dates In Desc Order

Comment: @Adeel yes just have the loop in reverse order: `for (DateTime curDate = now; curDate > past; curDate = curDate.AddDays(-1))`